# Pandas Dataframe to Code

Tags: python, pandas

If I have an existing pandas dataframe, is there a way to generate the python code, which when executed in another python script, will reproduce that dataframe.

e.g.

```
In[1]: df

Out[1]:
   income   user
0   40000    Bob
1   50000   Jane
2   42000  Alice

In[2]: someFunToWriteDfCode(df)

Out[2]: 
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
    ...:                    'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could try to use the to_dict() method on DataFrame:

```
print "df = pd.DataFrame( %s )" % (str(df.to_dict()))
```

If your data contains NaN's, you'll have to replace them with float('nan'):

```
print "df = pd.DataFrame( %s )" % (str(df.to_dict()).replace(" nan"," float('nan')"))
```

Comment: first part of solution requires brackets () for me to work, becoming 
print ("df = pd.DataFrame( %s )" % (str(df.to_dict())))

Comment: @josepmaria : my example was for python 2.7. if you are using python 3.x, you could try: 

print(f'df = pd.DataFrame( {str(df.to_dict())} )')

Answer (score 2):

## more general solution

Supported pd.DataFrame attributes:

- dtype of each column
- strings with substring `'nan'`
- index

### code

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

def _values_to_code(vals):
    """
    Code representation of values

    Parameters
    ----------
    vals : List

    Returns
    -------
    str :
        vals as code string
    """
    values = str(vals)
    values = re.sub(r" nan(?<![,\]])", " np.nan", values)
    return values

def _dtype_to_code(dtype):
    """
    Code representation of dtypes

    Parameters
    ----------
    dtypes : datatype
        dtype to convert. Example: np.float64

    Returns
    -------
    str :
        dtype as code string
    """
    dtype = str(dtype)
    dtype = re.sub(r"float64", " np.float64", dtype)
    dtype = re.sub(r"int64", " np.int64", dtype)
    return dtype


def df_to_code(df):
    code = "pd.DataFrame({"

    # columns with values
    for col in df.columns:
        values = _values_to_code(df[col].tolist())
        dtype = _dtype_to_code(df.dtypes[col])
        code += f'\n\t\'{col}\': np.array({values}, dtype={dtype}),'
    code += '\n}'

    # index
    values = _values_to_code(df.index)
    dtype = _dtype_to_code(df.index.dtype)
    code += f', index=pd.{values}'

    code += ')'
    return code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'simple_float': np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=float),
        'simple_int': np.array([4, 5, 6], dtype=int),
        'nan_variations': np.array(['np.nan', 'nan', np.nan], dtype=object),
        'fancy_content': np.array([4, 'x', [1, 2]], dtype=object),
    }, index = [0, '1', 2])

    # small unittest
    exec('df2 = ' + df_to_code(df))
    assert df.equals(df2)

    print(df_to_code(df))
```

### output

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    'simple_float': np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype= np.float64),
    'simple_int': np.array([4, 5, 6], dtype= np.int64),
    'nan_variations': np.array(['np.nan', 'nan', np.nan], dtype=object),
    'fancy_content': np.array([4, 'x', [1, 2]], dtype=object),
}, index=pd.Index([0, '1', 2], dtype='object'))
```

You can directly paste the output into a python console and enjoy ;)

### python console demonstration

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame({
...     'simple_float': np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype= np.float64),
...     'simple_int': np.array([4, 5, 6], dtype= np.int64),
...     'nan_variations': np.array(['np.nan', 'nan', np.nan], dtype=object),
...     'fancy_content': np.array([4, 'x', [1, 2]], dtype=object),
... }, index=pd.Index([0, '1', 2], dtype='object'))
   simple_float  simple_int nan_variations fancy_content
0           1.0           4         np.nan             4
1           2.0           5            nan             x
2           3.0           6            NaN        [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I always used this code which help me much

```
def gen_code(df):
    return 'pickle.loads({})'.format(pickle.dumps(df))

import pickle
code_string = gen_code(df)
code_string
```

So now you can copy the output of the `code_string` and paste it as follow to that string variable `A`

```
A= 'Paste your code_string here'
import pickle
df=eval(A)
```

This had helped me copy and past data frames in such platform

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that does not use dicts

```
import numpy as np

def dataframe_to_code(df):
    data = np.array2string(df.to_numpy(), separator=', ')
    data = data.replace(" nan", " float('nan')")
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    return f"""df = pd.DataFrame({data}, columns={cols})"""
```

The `data.replace(" nan", " float('nan')")` is optional and was inspired by madokis excellent answer.

Note that `np.array2string` only works for numpy versions 1.11 and higher.

I recommend using https://github.com/psf/black to format the output

Comment: In my case,  I had to add “from pandas import Timestamp” to work for dates, and add another replace line to replace “ NaT” with pd.NaT to deal with blank dates. Otherwise worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on other answers a little by adding NaT as a type.

```
def frame_to_code(frame):
    convert = str(frame.to_dict()).replace(" nan"," float('nan')").replace(" NaT"," pd.NaT")
    return f"df = pd.DataFrame({convert})"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can first save the dataframe you have, and then load in another python script when necessary. You can do it with two packages: `pickle` and `shelve`.

### To do it with `pickle`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
with open('dataframe', 'wb') as pfile:
    pickle.dump(df, pfile)           # save df in a file named "dataframe"
```

To read the dataframe in another file:

```
import pickle
with open('dataframe', 'rb') as pfile:
    df2 = pickle.load(pfile)        # read the dataframe stored in file "dataframe"
    print(df2)
```

Output:

```
    income  user
0   40000   Bob
1   50000   Jane
2   42000   Alice
```

#### To do it with `shelve`:

```
import pandas as pd
import shelve
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
with shelve.open('dataframe2') as shelf:
    shelf['df'] = df               # store the dataframe in file "dataframe"
```

To read the dataframe in another file:

```
import shelve
with shelve.open('dataframe2') as shelf:
    print(shelf['df'])             # read the dataframe
```

Output:

```
    income  user
0   40000   Bob
1   50000   Jane
2   42000   Alice
```

Comment: The question very clearly states 'generate python code'. There could be a number of reasons for this, maybe it is to run on a system that doesn't have access to a read/write filesystem. Neither pickle nor shelve creates python code.