# Generate the code that produces my observed dataframe (Multilevel index)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

I have a DataFrame on my Jupyter notebook, and I would like to generate a code that once I write can generate the same DataFrame I observe. The reason for my question is that I have a very large dataFrame and broke it down then applied a lot of difference techniques including pivot tables. Therefore, I would like to have my newly generated df.

I am expecting a function that I write like generate_dataframe out of (df) will give me the code that will generate this particular DataFrame which might contain multilevel index.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769882/pandas-dataframe-to-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## setup

Assuming you have `pickle` loaded already

```
import pickle
```

## solution

This function should generate the code you need.

```
def gen_code(df):
    return 'pickle.loads({})'.format(pickle.dumps(df))
```

## demonstration

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        A=[1, 2, 3],
        B=list('XYZ')
    ),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1)])
)

print(df)

     A  B
a 1  1  X
  2  2  Y
b 1  3  Z

code_string = gen_code(df)

print(eval(code_string))

     A  B
a 1  1  X
  2  2  Y
b 1  3  Z
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but will give you readable code that can be copied and pasted (if that matters).

(borrowing @piRSquared's sample data here)

```
def df_to_code(df):
    print( 'index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( ', df.index.tolist(), ')' )
    print( 'dct = ', df.to_dict() )
    print( 'new_df = pd.DataFrame( dct, index=index )' )

df_to_code(df)
```

Outputs:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(  [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1)] )
dct =  {'A': {('a', 1): 1, ('b', 1): 3, ('a', 2): 2}, 'B': {('a', 1): 'X', ('b', 1): 'Z', ('a', 2): 'Y'}}
new_df = pd.DataFrame( dct, index=index )
```

Those three lines are executable and will give you back the original dataframe:

```
new_df

     A  B
a 1  1  X
  2  2  Y
b 1  3  Z
```

Comment: I'd say that qualifies as useful